# How difficult are the quests from the terminal in the Orochi Group van in Blue Mountain?

Tags: the-secret-world

I finally polished off all of the 'Major' missions in Blue Mountain last night. Or at least, I thought I had, as I had done all the quests from every NPC marked on my map. Until, as I finished my last quest in the zone, I noticed a computer inside of a black van in the Orochi compound. It had two quests for me. Both were marked **devastating.**

Being a fearless sort, I picked up The Filth Amendment and tried it anyway. This was not a good idea. The mobs in the quarry tore me apart, and in short order, disabused of any notions of completion, I moved on to Egypt.

What I want to know though, is when should I return to Blue Mountain to take care of these quests? They were marked as devastating when I was in full QL6 gear with a QL8 weapon. At what point do these quests transition to Hard or Normal?

Comment: Maybe they aren't solo quests but group quests?

Comment: I believe the 'difficulty' is built up of a combination of gear quality level, skill points attained/assigned, ability points attained/assigned, and whether the quest is intended to be completed in a group. The reason I state this is for example the PvP quests, the difficulty marked on the quests will vary between 'Very Easy' and 'Devastating' on an identical character based on the number of people on your team. I've also noticed quests in the world changing marked difficulty based on subsequently gaining more skill points without changing any gear (ie: going from devastating to hard).

Comment: I actually think the way that difficulty is determined is worthy of a question of it's own - it's going to require a degree of investigation and testing I think to establish what exactly the contributing factors to the displayed difficulty is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shinrai has stated, **The Filth Amendment** is a QL10 mission if done solo, but can be done by a full group in QL6 gear. So either find some friends or come back when you've reached Transylvania (at which point you should be in QL10 gear).

The second quest is an investigation mission and involves no combat. It can be done at any level (although as usual the puzzles are pleasantly challenging in other ways).

Answer (score 3):

The quarry is one of those endgame spots intended for players with full QL10.  Even once you're in decent gear, you may need a group to properly tackle these mobs.  I have heard reports of QL6-8 characters doing it in a full group of 5, though, so it may be worth trying - you'll probably want a dedicated tank and healer.

Answer (score 0):

Just soloed it twice with ql 5 gear.  Its not that hard, if you are able to self heal and play smart.  Too bad I can't get the quest to update...but great exp 7k a kill !